# How to scrape multiple URLs effectively in BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find an effective way to scrape multiple pages in BS4. I am able to scrape the first page easily and get all of the data I need but unfortunately, not all data is on it. There are 2 other pages to scrape and rather than hard coding this and changing the URL for the second and third pages I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this in Python using BS4. The only part of the URL that needs to be changed is page=1 to the respective page number(either 1,2,3).

```
import csv 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.congress.gov/members?q={%22congress%22:%22115%22}&pageSize=250&page=1"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

names = soup.find_all()

items = soup.find_all("li","expanded")
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
    print(item.find("a"))
    with open('web.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([item.find("a").encode('utf-8')])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the difficult things with web scraping in general. BS4 can't help you generate logic to elegantly grab URLs and predict where the data you need is going to reside on a website. Every website is different and follows different rules on the backend.

The best thing you can do is look at the site itself and do your best to recognize patterns and pull in URLs dynamically based on what is on the page. The elegance of that logic is up to you and depends heavily on the site you're scraping.

Answer (score 1):

iterate over the page number. `itertools.count` comes in handy:

```
import itertools

for index in itertools.count(start=1):
    url = "https://www.congress.gov/members?q={%22congress%22:%22115%22}&pageSize=250&page="+str(index)

    # the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ways you can do the same. In this very case the better approach is to put the last page number as it's highest range. The webpage displays documents in three different pages and the highest number of page is `3`. However, if you search for `https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%7D&pageSize=250&page=5`, you can see that the webpage still shows the data whereas the stock of data have been exhausted in page 3. So, defining the last page number (plus 1) is what you should do here.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = "https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%7D&pageSize=250&page={}"
for link in [my_url.format(page) for page in range(1,4)]:
    res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".expanded"):
        name = item.select_one(".result-heading a").text
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of last page just iterate as proposed in answers above. In case last page index unknown - use while loop and a logic to decide whether to continue scraping next page or no.

```
import csv 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.congress.gov/members?q={%22congress%22:%22115%22}&pageSize=250&page="
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
pageId = 0

while True:
    pageId = pageId + 1
    print ("Processing page " + str(pageId))
    response = requests.get(url+str(pageId), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    names = soup.find_all()
    if len(name) == 0:
        break

    items = soup.find_all("li","expanded")
    for item in items:
        print(item.text)
        print(item.find("a"))
        with open('web.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerow([item.find("a").encode('utf-8')])
```